# Actual limit in excel is 1048576 . If the rows reached that level then it has to go to next sheet. Any suggestions

Tags: php, database, export-to-excel

Here is my code

```
$output = $filename.".xls";
$output = "../downloads/".$filename.".csv";
$output_zip = "../downloads/".$filename.".zip";
$fp = fopen($output, 'w');
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
if ($fp==false) echo "Failed to pen file stream";
$myArr = array();
while ($finfo = mysqli_fetch_field($res)) {
    $myArr[]=$finfo->name;
}   
fputcsv($fp,$myArr);
$my_i=1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row( $res )) {
    $myArr = array();
    foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
        $myArr[]=$value; 
    }
    fputcsv($fp,$myArr); $my_i++;
}                                
fclose( $fp );
```

Comment: You cannot do this with a basic CSV format file, because a CSV doesn't have any concept of "sheets".... you can only do this with a genuine native spreadsheet format such as BIFF (`.xls`), OfficeOpenXML (`.xlsx`), OASIS (Open/Libre Office Calc) or Gnumeric

Comment: Note also that the limit in BIFF-format Excel worksheets is 64k rows, not 1M

Answer (score 0):

A CSV or a text file can have many more rows than the Excel sheet limit.

If you want to bring that data into Excel, you can use Power Query to connect to a CSV file and make it available for processing in the spreadsheet. Power Query can also connect to many other data sources, any of which can return way more than the Excel row limit.

You may want to use 64 bit Office for projects that involve a lot of data.

Power Query is a [free download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) for Excel 2010 and 2013. In Excel 2016 for Windows, it is integrated into the Data ribbon.